# Hide group in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How with xpath expr replace (hide) group Configuration in project managment  module in tabs settings?

```
<group string="Configuration" groups="base.group_no_one">
      <field name="sequence" groups="base.group_no_one"/>
</group>
```

I'm try with below code but get error:

```
 <xpath expr="//group[@string='Configuration']" position="replace">
 </xpath>
```

Comment: you have to hide configuration menu without debug mode right?

Comment: @i'mPosSible  Hi, I want hide this --> https://postimg.org/image/55wt5h5m1/   I'm inherit project module and in new module need hide this group!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the error you are getting is a `ParseError`, because you are using the `string` attribute as a selector inside your XPath expression, which is not allowed since Odoo v9.0.

Instead, you might try to find the `sequence` field and the select the parent:

```xml
<xpath expr="//field[@name='sequence']/.." position="replace">
</xpath>
```

However, replacing the whole element might not be the best solution, because other modules might use the group or the sequence field inside an inherited view, which would cause an error. A better solution would be to hide the group using the `invisible` attribute. The full record could look something like this:

```xml
<record id="edit_project_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="model">project.project</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.edit_project"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='sequence']/.." position="attributes">
            <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```